# REACT-Toastify - Duplicates toasts

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I just added React-Toastify to my REACT app. I have the below code in my Apps.js

```
import { ToastContainer, Slide } from "react-toastify";
import "react-toastify/dist/ReactToastify.css";

function App() {
  return (
    <>
      <Router basename={process.env.PUBLIC_URL}>
        <div className="container-fluid">
          <NavHeader />
          <hr />
          <Switch>
            <Route exact path="/" component={HomePage} />
            <Route path="/about" component={AboutPage} />
            <Route path="/contact" component={ContactPage} />
          </Switch>
        </div>
      </Router>
      <div>
        <ToastContainer transition={Slide} />
      </div>
    </>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Then in my other pages, I display the Toast using the code below.

```
  showToastMessage(messageText, messageType = "I") {
    toast.dismiss();
    toast.configure({
      position: toast.POSITION.BOTTOM_RIGHT,
      toastId: 1
    });
    if (messageType === "S") {
      toast.success(messageText);
    }
    if (messageType === "I") {
      toast.info(messageText);
    }
    if (messageType === "E") {
      toast.error(messageText);
    }
  }
```

When I run the app, the toast is **displayed** in the **bottom right and top right corner** of my page.

I have done a lot of searches and did come across [this thread](https://github.com/fkhadra/react-toastify/issues/274) and applied the changes suggested, but I am still getting duplicates!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

if you use **ToastContainer** and **toast function** each together, you will see two toastify.
You should use only one.

---

Your code design some complex. Let me show how to use basic toastify you will understand it.

Firstyle import package. (Step 1)

```
import { toast } from 'react-toastify';
import 'react-toastify/dist/ReactToastify.css';
```

Now, you can call toast. (Step 2)

```
 toast.configure();

 toast.success("Success Notification !", {
    position: toast.POSITION.TOP_CENTER
  });

  toast.error("Error Notification !", {
    position: toast.POSITION.TOP_LEFT
  });

  toast.warn("Warning Notification !", {
    position: toast.POSITION.BOTTOM_LEFT
  });

  toast.info("Info Notification !", {
    position: toast.POSITION.BOTTOM_CENTER
  });
```

that's it.

Comment: According to the docs: https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-toastify, it says to use the ToastContainer at the root of your app so that you can use it across the app.

Comment: ToastContainer is component. So if you call this component, you will see notification immediately. In epitome, starting v5 the ToastContainer is optional if you want to. (https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-toastify#what-if-i-told-you-that-the-toastcontainer-is-optional)

Comment: Thanks! I now got it. I just had to add `toast.configure();` to my App.js

Comment: How can i replace toast.error message onclick.if the response was coming from api.

Comment: This solution may have worked earlier, but if i remove the toastcontainer component, it gives error, and toast.configure is now also deprecated.

Answer (score 2):

Add your  `<ToastContainer/>` to `App.tsx` or whatever you named your default root `App.js` file. After that, DO NOT add `<ToastContainer/>` to elsewhere.

```
      <ToastContainer 
            position='top-right' 
            autoClose={5000}
            hideProgressBar={false}
            newestOnTop={false}
            closeOnClick
            rtl={false}
            pauseOnFocusLoss
            draggable
            pauseOnHover
        />
```

Comment: Thank you, I was adding a ToastContainer on each page that I've had, that's why mi toast got duplicated.

Answer (score -2):

```
import React from 'react';
import Routes from './route/route';
import { ToastContainer, toast } from 'react-toastify';

class App extends React.Component {
constructor() {
super();
}

componentDidMount() {
let root = document.querySelector('#root');
root.children[0].remove()
}

render() {
return (
  <>
    <ToastContainer
      position="top-right"
      autoClose={5000}
      hideProgressBar={false}
      newestOnTop={false}
      closeOnClick
      rtl={false}
      pauseOnFocusLoss
      draggable
      pauseOnHover
    />
    
    <ToastContainer />
    <Routes />
   </>
    )
   }
  }

  export default App;
```

So in ComponentDidMount two lines solve my problem, Actually in my case IDK why The ToastContainer component render twice so i remove the one of them.

[image]